# is possible to Read json file in another server and how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, get

my json file like this

```
[{
 "code": "Free",
 "type": "base",
 "name": "Start",
 "price": "Free",
 "subscriptionunit": "month",
 "subscriptionqty": 1,
 "customizable": false

}]
```

This **json** file in separate server and my web server another server I coded like this to get json detail from same same server and same project.

```
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: './json/priceplan.json',
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, X-Requested-With",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },

            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("Ok : " + data);                       

                })
                .error(function (data) {    
                    console.log("Error : " + data);
                });
```

I want to know how retrieve json file in separate server.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers *client-side*. That doesn't work, those headers are required to be in the **response** from the server, not the request from the client.

You'll have to modify the other server to enable CORS from the origin you're making the request from. This is a server-side thing.

Comment: I already enable CORS other server.but I didn't get any result

Comment: @brk: Yes, but then the thing being fetched isn't a JSON file anymore.

Comment: @Lakmi: Then you didn't enable it correctly. Browsers aren't broken, CORS does work. But remove those headers from the request. CORS is header-sensitive. Just do your request normally, and then adjust the server-sent headers accordingly.

Comment: @Crowder: ok i'll try it again thnx

Comment: @Crowder : when I try to test local host i got error like this :  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Lakmi: Which tells you you're not sending the appropriate headers from the server. It's worth having a really thorough read of the spec linked above. Note that the error you've quoted says "preflight" -- perhaps you're not handling the `OPTIONS` request? Just `GET`?

Comment: @Crowder : i send header like this :     headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, X-Requested-With",
                    "Content-Type": "text/json"
                },

Comment: @Lakmi: "Handling the OPTIONS request" means just that: Processing a request from the client with the HTTP verb OPTIONS. Again: Read the spec.

Comment: i fixed it ,i copied json file to same server now it's work thnx @Crowder

Answer (score -2):

if other server is in internet, then you will have to host website (allow MIME type json on iis) on that server with some domain name e.g. www.xyz.com.

in publish folder of www.xyz.com site store your json and access it with URL e.g. www.xyz.com/file/test.json

else if both servers on same server, then you dont have to buy domain

Comment: this is not related to this question.i have two separate server web and service i want to get json file details in server to web server.